# Laravel Eloquent belongsToMany only fetches one result

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

My `belongsToMany` function only returns a single element when it should return all of them.

This is my table structure (simplified):

`users`

- id
- ...

`groups`

- id
- ...

`users_in_groups`

- id
- user_id
- group_id

This is my function:

```php
    public function getUsers(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            UserDao::class,
            'users_in_groups',  //table
            'id',               //foreignPivotKey
            "user_id"           //relatedPivotKey
        );
    }
```

I call the `getResults()` method on the result and even then it only has a single object in the `items` array.

The table is well filled when I manually look it up. What am I missing?

Comment: return $this->belongsToMany( UserDao::class, 'users_in_groups', //table 'user_id', //foreignPivotKey "group_id" //relatedPivotKey );

Comment: i think even you can remove both ids since its matching naming convention

Comment: @JohnLobo That did almost work, I just had to change the order of "user_id" and "group_id". Thanks a lot! Post that as an answer and I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: @JohnLobo No I can't, because its not really "users" and "groups" but domain-specific terms I didn't want to confuse you with ;)

Comment: oaky.np :)have a great day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like issue is with `$foreignPivotKey` and  `$relatedPivotKey`

```
public function belongsToMany($related, $table = null, $foreignPivotKey = null, $relatedPivotKey = null,
                              $parentKey = null, $relatedKey = null, $relation = null)
```

So your relationship should be

```
 public function getUsers(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            UserDao::class,
            'users_in_groups',
            "group_id" ,    
            'user_id',               
                   
        );
    }
```

Also both

Comment: Almost! But "group_id" has to come before "user_id"

Comment: updated my answer. i think if you are in group model then it should similar i guess. since i always follow table naming convention .so very rarely using extra params